# Generic objects in Apache Thrift

Tags: java, thrift

I want to know if I can define "generic objects" in Apache Thrift with IDL language, something like "Object" class in Java.

I need to send objects's list of any type, but I don't know how can I define this in the file.thrift

Like this:

```
struct
{
   1: list<object> listObjects;
}
```

or

```
struct
{
   1: list<?> listObjects;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Apache Thrift does not support struct inheritance or self referential structs. This makes what you would like to do, passing a polymorphic list directly, impossible. There are ways to work around this, for instance serializing objects to binary and then passing a list of binaries, de-serializing them on the other end.

```
struct abc {
    1: list<binary> myList,
}
```

All Apache Thrift structs have read and write methods which you can use to serialize them to a memory buffer (TMemoryBuffer) which you can then use as a binary object for the list. Another option might be to use a union.

```
union myTypes {
    1: double dbl
    2: i64 bigInt
    3: SomeOtherStruct sos
}

struct abc {
    1: list<myTypes> myList,
}
```

This approach creates a list of the myTypes union type, but the union can house any IDL defined type you like.

Comment: A couple weeks back DAG support was added to the Apache Thrift abstraction. Only C++ implements this feature currently but I expect we will eventually get full language coverage. It is now possible to pass tree structures of self referential nodes. Early days still but a useful new feature.