# Thrift type modelling for List<HashMap<String,Object>>

Tags: java, thrift

I've a service method in Java with following return type:

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>>
```

How can I best model it in thrift?

Answer (score 6):

Pretty straightforward:

```
struct MyObjectData {
    // data of your objects
}

list< map< string, MyObjectData>>
```

You may want to make it a type:

```
typedef list< map< string, MyObjectData>>   MyObjectStructure
```

The caveat lies in the data structure of `MyObjectData`. If by `Object` you literally mean **any** `Object`, then we've got a problem. Thrift can't handle generic cases like this, because it does not support structures derived from each other (like you can do with `class`). What you can do is, to use a `union` holding different kinds of structs, where only one is used at a time:

```
struct Foo { /* some fields */ }
struct Bar { /* some fields */ }

// a union allows us to store different kinds of structs in one list
union Generic {
  1: Foo foo
  2: Bar bar
}

// technically, a union is more or less a struct with optional fields, 
struct Alternative {
  1: optional Foo foo
  2: optional Bar bar
}
```

In case you need derived structures, I have solved this problem for me by doing this:

```
struct Base { 
    // some fields
}

struct Derived { 
    1: Base base_
    // some more fields
}
```

which works quite well for me. If you have a deep inheritance tree, it might become somewhat painful to work with, but that's not the case in my particular case.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK thrift does not directly support generic Object types which can be type casted to/from any object you like. You'll have to specifically define your object as in above example. You can't have a return type as Object.
There's a work around mentioned here:
[Generic objects in Apache Thrift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845752/generic-objects-in-apache-thrift)